# MS Access Tab control in different locations on form for different users

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access database with a number of forms.  The back end seems to be working just fine, but the forms are causing me some trouble.  When I open them, they look fine, but when coworkers open them, the Tab Control is in a different location, and on top of other controls.  This is bad from a functional and aesthetic perspective.  I have another form where this doesn't seem to be the case, and I'm not sure what is different.  How can I lock down the location of the Tab Control so it doesn't appear in different places for different people?
This is how it looks on my computer:
[image: How it looks on my computer]
This is how it looks to others - the Tab Control is shifted up:
[image: How it looks to others]

Comment: Can you post screenshots of how the form looks for you and for your coworkers?

Comment: is the size of your tab control larger than its container (form/subform)?

Comment: Can't you just debug the code on a co-worker's machine to see WHY this tab control is moving around ? Solving the problem is better than hiding it, and I never saw (yet) controls moving by their own will.

Answer (score 0):

Put the tab control in a container such as a panel and assign a location to the container.

Comment: Where do you add a panel?  I'm not seeing something with that name.